# Regular Expression to get surrounding text, but not matching words in between

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to write a regular expression to extract URLs, which have endpoints with the following format:

`https://api.siteurl.com/id/a1b2c3d4/apps`

`https://api.siteurl.com/id/a1b2c3d4/devices`

`...`

`etc`

The id in these urls are `a1b2c3d4`, and can differ between URLs, but I want to extract the text that surrounds it:

The following regular expression matches the entire string:

`https:\/\/\S+\.\S+\.com\/id\/\S+\/\S+`

However, I don't want to extract the id itself, and just want to use it as a lookahead.

The final extracted string should be like `https://api.siteurl.com/id'...'apps'`

Where the `...` is not actually extracted.

Is it only possible to do this using 2 regexes, where each uses a look-ahead and a look-behind, or can a single expression be used to extract just the relevant parts of the url?

Comment: You should use brackets to mark extracted part: `https:\/\/\S+\.\S+\.com\/id\/([^\/]+)\/`

Comment: What regex environment?

Comment: Maybe you want [2 captured groups](https://regex101.com/r/WvCCXY/1) `(https:\/\/\S+\.\S+\.com\/id)\/(?:[^\/]+\/)(\S+)`

Comment: Awesome, that works.

Comment: @Thefourthbird I think you may answer this question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That is a while ago I see :) I have added an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use 2 capturing groups to capture the data that you want to keep, and match the data that you don't want to keep.

```
(https:\/\/\S+\.\S+\.com\/id)\/[^\/]+\/(\S+)
```

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `https:\/\/\S+\.\S+\.com\/id` Match the start of the string till `id` without `/`
- `)` Close group
- `\/` Match the `/` following
- `[^\/]+\/` Match +1 times any char except `/`, then match `/`
- `(\S+)` Capture **group 2** Match 1+ times a non whitespace char

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YcCxiz/1)

This is the pattern from the comment without the non capturing group `(?:` as it is unnecessary.